# How can I remove subscript out of bound error

Tags: sml, smlnj

It is clear. I had following error.
How can I remove it. I need to process all of the list.

```
uncaught exception Subscript [subscript out of bounds]
 raised at: Basis/Implementation/list.sml:...
```

It's in SML/NJ and I am working with lists.

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means you're trying to access an element with an index that isn't in the list.

For instance:

```
- List.nth([0,1,2], 7);

uncaught exception Subscript [subscript out of bounds]
  raised at: Basis/Implementation/list.sml:47.35-47.44
```

You solve this problem by not trying to access nonexistent elements. You should generally be careful with dealing with functions like `List.nth`, `List.take`, `List.drop`, ..., as they're partial functions, which only work for certain inputs.